# NoSuchElementException in selenium(java)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm getting the 'No Such Element' exception in this case:

```
user_name=driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
```

The corresponding HTML snippet is:

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" style="background-   
image: none; position: absolute;" autocomplete="off"   
spellcheck="false">
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: That id may be same for other web element in your webpage. Use this xpath instead of id. try this xpath: //input[@name='username']. If you still get the same exception try to take the xpath from its parent tag.

Comment: Is it possible that `findElement(By.id(...))` is a typo?  Should it be `getElementById(...)` instead?

Comment: @SarithaG Thanks for the prompt reply...but using the xpath you provided is still giving the same problem. The webpage only consists of login id and password...so why would it have another web element with same id?

Comment: @r12 i don't think so as another program using it is working fine.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id()) is correct only.

Comment: Which Url are you using???

Comment: @SarithaG The website is on intranet so you won;t be able to access it.

Comment: Ok...can you post full html code?

Comment: @SarithaG Got it working with id...just had to add thread.sleep()  :)